# Changing the color of the y-axis for MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

Pretty basic question : how to change the color of the y-axis values in a line chart. I need the background of the chart to be a specific color, with the y-axis values being white.

[image]

I need the values of the y-axis to be white, instead of black.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 6):

Get YAxis of your chart object and set Text Color.

```
mChart.getYAxis().setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
```

if you want to change axisline color, you can use below method.

```
mChart.getYAxis().setAxisLineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor));
```

Answer (score 5):

in the new version the library changed so it can be

```
mpLineChart.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
mpLineChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisLineColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 0):

And in the new, new version:

```
mpLineChart.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
mpLineChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.white));
```